# Defining a non-commutative algebra

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, quantum-computing

I'm new to Mathematica, and I'm trying to learn the ropes.
I'm trying to write a little boson algebra engine, with basic useful functions such as non-commutative algebra, normal-ordering and vacuum expectation values.

So, for starters I define the following OpProd[] function,

```
OpProd[a_ + b_, c_] := OpProd[a, c] + OpProd[b, c];
OpProd[a_, b_ + c_] := OpProd[a, b] + OpProd[a, c];
OpProd[c_, a_] := c a /; NumericQ[c] == True;
OpProd[left__, a_, b_] = OpProd[left, OpProd[a, b]];
```

which simply defines the basic properties of the algebra, and seems to work fine.

My problem is that I'd like to have an alias for OpProd[], so that whenever I write a^ b^ c^, or any string like that, Mathematica would use OpProd[] to implement the product.

```
(*Shorthand notation for operator products*)
Unprotect[Times];

\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(a__\), \(^\)]\) 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(b__\), \(^\)]\) := OpProd[a, b];
Protect[Times];
```

This unfortunately does not seem to work, outputting just

```
In[10]:= 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(a\), \(^\)]\) 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(b\), \(^\)]\) 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(c\), \(^\)]\) 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(d\), \(^\)]\) 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(e\), \(^\)]\) // Simplify

Out[10]= OpProd[a, b] OpProd[c, d] 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(e\), \(^\)]\)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are [quite a few questions about noncommutative algebra on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Non+commutative+algebra). Could you start by looking through those and seeing if any of them help you with your problem.

Comment: Do not misuse a built in operator like Times, this is calling for troubles. Use e.g. NonCommutativeMultiply instead.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Is your algebra associative? How many dimensions does it have? If it is associative and finite-dimensional, you simply can represent it as matrices.

Comment: There is a symbol `**` in Mathematica that is called "non-commutative multiply".